# Getting the ID number into the Title automatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a way to get the ID number that's assigned to auto populate into the Title Field as well?

Comment: In which way you are doing with CSOM or JSOM?

Answer (score 3):

Your options are:

- SharePoint Workflow (2010 or 2013 versions will both work) and is supported in O365 and On Premise.
- Event Receivers in On Premise will also do this, but this seems heavy handed for a simple field update.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the ID is generated late by a proces that checks the underlying database, then does a +1 and sets the (internal) ID field.

That is the reason why using ID in Calculated Columns has an issue, 
because the order is:

1. Update Calculated Columns in Item
2. Get ID

Which causes ID used in Calculated Columns to be 0 **FOR NEW ITEMS**

ID will be correct on the next Item Update.. 
and because updating the Formula itself again updates ALL items; people **think** ID in a Calculated Column works fine

You can work around it with a New Item Workflow:

- Get the ID value (the workflow runs after the New-Item ID assignment)
- Append it to the Title

Answer (score 0):

Here is a paper talking about how to add Doc ID in File Name with an Event Receiver solution.
http://blog.wombit.se/2013/10/24/sharepoint-2010-document-id-in-file-name/

Answer (score 0):

1. If your are using Infopath form to populate this information you could do this quite easily by getting the list ID max value and increment it by one and append that value to the title field. If you are using html form and post data by REST or JSOM then you append ID before submitted the data to the list
2. You could use a workflow (for code free solution) or event receiver post item created